# how `clear` prevent margin collapsing?

Tags: css, margin

[margin collapse](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) is disbled in the following case:

> If the top and bottom margins of an element with clearance are adjoining, its margins collapse with the adjoining margins of following siblings but that resulting margin does not collapse with the bottom margin of the parent block.

what does it mean?can u give me some concrete examples?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Posting your code also helps.

Comment: @jnkrois This is a specification question rather than one about some specific code. I personally find it clear enough as I've worked on implementing margin collapsing in a browser engine, but a full answer with examples is rather detailed. The best place for the answers here are the spec compliance tests found in the CSS testing repo.

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This ensures that a clear prevents any following elements from overlapping the floats.**

Let's start with floats and clear for now. Floats can **overflow their parent**:

```
<div style='border:1px solid green;'>
    <div style='float:left;background:red;height:100px;width:40px;'></div>
    That red box overflows!
</div>
```

If we add a clearing div, it never will. A clear is like saying nothing else can flow above this line:

```
<div style='border:1px solid green;'>
    <div style='float:left;background:red;height:100px;width:40px;'></div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <!-- Anything down here will not overlap the floats -->
</div>
```

However, margin collapsing breaks things a little, because **following elements can collapse 'through' something, going all the way up to the very top of the top margin**. Let's have a quick excursion into certain aspects of margin collapsing.

## Self collapsing hacks

In general, margin collapsing applies to *any* top margin which is directly touching *any* bottom margin.

That includes an elements own top/bottom margins too. This is called **self-collapsing**, and **margin collapsing happens repeatedly**. Here's a quick example of both of these things together:

```
<div style='margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:30px;'></div>
<div style='margin-top:30px; border:1px solid black;'>
    The gap above me is only 30px, not 90!
</div>
```

That first div entirely self-collapses, resulting in a computed space of 30px, then the second div collapses into that too, keeping the space at just 30px.

Ok, so we've now got a rough idea of what self-collapsing is. Now let's start trying to abuse that with a  **self-collapsing clearing div**:

```
<div style='border:1px solid green;'>
    <div style='float:left;background:red;height:100px;width:40px;'></div>
    <div style='clear:left;margin-top:90px;margin-bottom:90px;'></div>
    I'm after the clear and look, no 90px gap!
</div>
```

The margin is still there though. It actually runs **90px upwards over the floats**.

Next, imagine there was no text after it, and the parent had a bottom margin. By our margin collapsing rules, **it should collapse upwards**. Sibling elements might even collapse 'through' it, all the way up to the top. We don't want that, because it would cause some unwanted overlapping.

This part of the specification blocks this behaviour. Let's break the spec's language down to make that clearer:

> If the top and bottom margins of an element with clearance are adjoining

This is describing a self-collapsing element which has cleared a float.

> its margins collapse with the adjoining margins of following siblings

It's fine for other margins to collapse into it, but..

> That resulting margin does not collapse with the bottom margin of the parent block.

..the very bottom margin must not collapse upwards, because that would result in our awkward overlapping case.

Here's an example of the case where the rule is applied:

```
<div style='border:1px solid green;'>
    <!-- A parent block with a bottom margin, and no border -->
    <div style='margin-bottom:50px;'>
        <div style='float:left;background:red;height:100px;width:40px;'></div>
        <!-- A self collapsing cleared div -->
        <div style='clear:left;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;'></div>
        <!-- The parents bottom margin is adjacent to our collapsed margin, 
        but it gets blocked from collapsing upwards. We see a gap here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding some text into that clearing div makes it no longer self collapse, but its bottom margin then safely collapses with the bottom margin of the parent instead.